# How to put formula based order in Rankx (Power BI)?

Tags: powerbi, rank

Am trying to sort a ranking column in matrix based on IF condition, but the Rankx doesn't accept a formula other than ASC/TRUE/1 0R DESC/FALSE/0 .
The if condition basically provide ouput as either 1 or 0.

Ex:

VAR A= IF(x>y,1,0)
Return Rankx(table, expression,,A,Dense)

Answer (score 0):

Change your measure to:

```
vyz = 
VAR A = IF(TODAY()> TODAY()-1
, Rankx(ALL('Table'), [Measure],, 1, Dense) // TRUE order 1
,Rankx(ALL('Table'), [Measure],, 0, Dense) // FALSE order 0
) 

Return 
A
```